# Installing QGIS using homebrew on El Capitan

Tags: homebrew

So I have been trying to install QGIS using homebrew on El Cap for a while now, but with very limited succes (I installed it once without any of the extras; `--with-grass7 --with-saga-gis --with-orfeo --with-r`. But I need these options). I have previously installed using the KyngChaos package but it was difficult to get it to work with other homebrew packages, so I thought that installing QGIS through brew would make everything easier.

This is the error in my log file:

Errors in:

```
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/d.out.file
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/d.polar
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/d.correlate
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/d.to.rast
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/d.rast.leg
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/d.shade
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/d.redraw
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/d.rast.edit
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/d.what.rast
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/db.droptable
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/db.dropcolumn
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/d.what.vect
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/db.in.ogr
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/db.out.ogr
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/db.test
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/db.univar
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/g.extension.all
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/i.colors.enhance
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/g.extension
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/g.manual
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/i.image.mosaic
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/i.in.spotvgt
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/i.oif
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/i.spectral
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/i.tasscap
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/m.proj
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.blend
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.colors.stddev
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.buffer.lowmem
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.fillnulls
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.grow
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.in.aster
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/i.pansharpen
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.in.srtm
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.in.wms
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.mask
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.out.xyz
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.pack
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.plane
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.rgb
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.reclass.area
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.shade
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.tileset
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r.unpack
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/r3.in.xyz
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.build.all
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.centroids
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.db.addcolumn
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.db.addtable
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.db.join
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.db.dropcolumn
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.db.droprow
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.db.droptable
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.db.renamecolumn
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.db.reconnect.all
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.db.update
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.db.univar
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.dissolve
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.in.e00
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.in.lines
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.in.geonames
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.in.mapgen
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.in.wfs
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.rast.stats
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.report
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.pack
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.to.lines
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.unpack
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.what.strds
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.what.vect
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/wxpyimgview
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/scripts/v.krige
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.topology
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.support
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.create
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.info
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.merge
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.list
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.remove
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.sample
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.register
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.unregister
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.accumulate
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.accdetect
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.aggregate
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.aggregate.ds
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.to.rast3
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.colors
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.univar
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.mapcalc
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.list
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.neighbors
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.series
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.export
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.out.vtk
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.import
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.gapfill
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast.extract
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast3d.list
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast3d.extract
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast3d.mapcalc
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rename
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.rast3d.univar
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.select
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.snap
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.vect.list
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.shift
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.vect.db.select
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.vect.export
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.vect.extract
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.vect.import
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.vect.what.strds
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.vect.observe.strds
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/temporal/t.vect.univar
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/gui/wxpython/gmodeler
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/gui/wxpython/animation
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/gui/wxpython/mapswipe
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/gui/wxpython/rlisetup
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/gui/wxpython/psmap
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/gui/wxpython/dbmgr
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/gui/wxpython/vdigit
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/gui/wxpython/iclass
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/gui/wxpython/gcp
/private/tmp/grass-7020151123-17790-lb9dkx/grass-7.0.1/gui/wxpython/timeline
```

Any help would be appreciated:-)